# Compiling GNU GCC tarball in Solaris 10 SPARC

Tags: gcc, makefile, solaris, gnu

I have a Sun/Oracle SPARC server with Solaris 10 SPARC installed onto it

I have the following GNU applications installed in my /usr/local directory (compiled using GCC 3.4.3 standard compiler installed during Solaris 10 SPARC installation)

GMP-4.3.2
MPFR-3.0.0
MPC-1.0.1

I want to try and compile a newer version of GNU GCC Compiler than the standard GCC 3.4.3 that came with Solaris 10 SPARC

I have three tarball extracted onto my HDD containing Solaris 10 SPARC...

GCC-5.1.0
GCC-7.1.0
GCC-9.1.0

I can configure each one successfully however when I try and compile any of the tarballs (gmake) I am confronted with the following error message each time GCC 3.4.3.  C compiler tries to convert each individual file into a compiled *.o file

```
cc1plus: warning -Wmissing-format-attribute ignored without -Wformat
```

What does this mean and how can I rectify it?

Thanks in advance for any help I can receive

Answer (score 1):

It means it will not warn you about calls to functions like sprintf or scanf that are missing arguments.  Since you are building already released code and not modifying the gcc code, you can just ignore it.

Comment: OK I have issued a gmake command using the OPENCSW gcc-4.6.3 Gcc gnu compiler. Having compiled Gcc-9.1.0 for approx 25 hours. I get the following error message

Comment: configure: loading cache ./config.cache

Comment: checking for sparc-sun-solaris2.10-gcc...  /export/home/Repo/gcc-9.1.0/host-sparc-sun-solaris2.10/prev-gcc/xgcc -B/export/home/Repo/gcc-9.1.0/host-sparc-sun-solaris2.10/prev-gcc/ -B/usr/local/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/usr/local/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/usr/local/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/include -isystem /usr/local/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/sys-include   -fchecking=1

Comment: checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/export/home/Repo/gcc-9.1.0/host-sparc-sun-solaris2.10/intl':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: Please find the config.log output at the Following URL  http://tab140.freewebspace.com/config-gcc9.txt

Comment: If anyone can help Id be so happy!!! I desperately need to get an upgraded vesrion of GCC installed if anyone can help . THANKS :)

Comment: @greenelephant: as you can see, asking new questions in the comments doesn't work, try opening a new question.  Also, the config.log link you gave shows the compiler passing the create executables test, so isn't the log matching the output you gave.